# Tomcat download issue in Cargo Container in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, tomcat, cargo-maven2-plugin

I am facing below error in Jenkins (I am using cargo plugin with tomcat for integration tests).

> [2021-07-20T09:46:47.790Z] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.9:start (start-server) on project demo-prj-rest-test: Execution start-server of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.9:start failed: Failed to download [https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/8.0.42/tomcat-8.0.42.zip]: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 1]

Below is my cargo plugin:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <timeout>600000</timeout>
            <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
            <type>installed</type>
            <zipUrlInstaller>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/8.0.42/tomcat-8.0.42.zip</url>
                <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/downloads</downloadDir>
                <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extracts</extractDir>
            </zipUrlInstaller>
            <output>${project.build.directory}/cargo-container.log</output>
            <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
        </container>
        <deployables>
            <deployable>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>demo-prj-war</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
                <location>${project.build.directory}/demo-prj-war</location>
                <properties>
                    <context>demo-prj-war</context>
                </properties>
            </deployable>
        </deployables>
        <configuration>
            <type>standalone</type>
            <home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat8x/container</home>
            <configfiles>
                <configfile>
                    <file>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/war-dependencies/context.xml</file>
                    <todir>conf/</todir>
                    <tofile>context.xml</tofile>
                </configfile>
            </configfiles>
            <properties>
                <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-server</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-server</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This works perfectly in local maven build with all integration tests run successfully in the cargo tomcat but facing above mentioned issue in Jenkins build.

Comment: As the message says: it is a connection timeout. How often did you try it again?

Comment: Does Jenkins run on the same local machine, or is it behind a fw or something like that?

Comment: Issue is resolved, you can find the cause and solution below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week we found the root cause of this issue. There was nothing wrong with the plugin configuration. The issue was on Jenkins side (a memory problem where the tomcat service within cargo just shuts down and doesn't return any useful error messages).

Solution:- We switched to a different maven pipeline.